# Curl for vmware

Tags: curl, vsphere

I am facing a unique issue while using curl.
I have a VSphere web client installed and running fine.I have couple of datastores in it.
I installed the REST Client on firefox and I am able to get the information related to all the datastores.
However, while using the curl command on linux, it shows me only the datastores and not the contents of any datastore.
For example, I have 2 datastores, namely DS1 and DS2. Inside the DS1 and DS2, I can see the VM files through the REST CLient. However the curl keeps on showing me the list of datastores even though I put the correct URL.

```
 curl --insecure -u root:pass https://172.28.18.181/folder?dcPath=ha-datacenter  ----> This shows me DS1 and DS2
 curl --insecure -u root:pass https://172.28.18.181/folder?dcPath=ha-datacenter&dsName=DS1  -----> This again shows me DS1 and DS2

curl version :
libcurl-7.19.7-37.el6_4.x86_64
curl-7.19.7-37.el6_4.x86_64
```

Can someone please help me out ?

Thanks,
Nikhil.

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution.Since the second curl command has some special characters in it, I need to use single quotes for the url.
I used 'https://172.28.18.181/folder?dcPath=ha-datacenter&dsName=DS1' and it worked fine.

Thanks,
Nikhil.